# PowerShell equivalent to "cut -c" in Bash

Tags: powershell, cut

I'm trying to learn PowerShell.

On Bash, I analyze data with the "cut -c" command with multiple positions
For example, if we have this input file:

```
Get-Process | tail > 1.txt # let's create an example file without headers...
```

To get the positions of each line from the 4'th to the 7'th characters and from the character range 57-72.

```
Get-Content .\1.txt | ForEach-Object { $_.substring(4,3)+ ' ' + $_.substring(57,15) }
```

That's a lot of typing... is there a better way?

An equivalent to the above in Bash is :

```
 cut -c 4-7,57-72 1.log
```

Comment: `To get the positions of each line from the [...cut, cut...]` Why? What are you actually trying to accomplish here? What is your desired end result?

Comment: e.g.  `echo "abc def ghik" | cut -c 2-3,11` returns "bci"  which are the second, third, and the eleventh characters of the string "abc def ghik" - what is the shortest way to  accomplish this in PowerShell then typing substring after substering like so: `echo "abc def ghik" | ForEach-Object { $_.substring(1,2) + $_.substring(10,1)}`

Comment: take a look at >>> `-join ('1234567890'.ToCharArray()[2,3,9])` <<<

Comment: Oh, pardon me, I didn't quite understand what you were trying to do with the processes but now I see. This should be a shorter, working alternative (atleast in this case) `"abc def ghik"[1..2+10] -join ""`

Comment: notjustme: this is exactly what I was looking for thank you so much.

Comment: @sagivba Please update your original question to include the example in the comments and accept my answer as a solution to your problem if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter way for your specific example in your comments could be something like this;

```
"abc def ghik"[1..2+10] -join ""
```